# Better battery saver linux between ubuntu mate and xubuntu

Tags: power-management, mate-desktop, xubuntu, battery, lightweight

I have tried xubuntu, lubuntu and ubuntu mate. I found xubuntu and ubuntu mate desktop environment good. My main concern is battery saving.  Which saves better battery between Ubuntu mate and xubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu MATE comes with TLP pre-installed so will provide better battery endurance.

Comment: I have tried all of these 3 desktop environment and found out the same battery performance in these. So I am now using ubuntu mate which gives me a battery backup of 3 hours (same as I get for windows 8). How to extend the battery life more than that. I have went through different desktop managers like i3 but don't know how to use it.